# how to create a separate header for a specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a custom php header file and named it `header-membersclub.php` and replaced the default header line with this code in `page.php`:

```
<?php 
if(is_page(7)) { 
   get_header('membersclub'); 
} else { 
   get_header(); 
} 
wp_head(); 
?>
```

but for some reason its not working. can somebody help me on this ? I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Be more specific with your questions and include code examples

Comment: Provide screenshots too because it gives a better idea where you are implementing this and your whole WordPress layout structure.

Comment: try posting it on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code:

```
<?php 
if(is_page($post->ID)) { //checking the current post not only 7
   get_header('membersclub'); 
} else { 
   get_header(); 
} 
?>
```

i removed `wp_head();` that is something it should be inside `<head>`.